# Most efficient way to store an object via serialization

Tags: c#, serialization

This is more of a design question, I'm looking for a good approach:

I have an Object  which consists of a few properties (some `Integers` and a `byte[] array`).

I'm using `BinaryFormatter` to serialize my objects - I'm holding a `List<T>` of all objects at any given time.

- When the application starts up, I de-serialize the file in which the objects were de-serialized to.
- When the application closes, I serialize the whole `List<T>` and save up everything to the file.

My problem is: In case of a system failure, the objects I hold in my `List<T>` will obviously get lost, since I serialize the `List<T>` only when the application shuts down normally.

I'm not looking into **de-serializing** & **serializing** each time I want to insert an object to my List, since that will be very expensive.

The solution I thought of is to hold a local database with a `BLOB` column to which the Objects will be serialized to, but I'm not too sure of this approach.

Any thoughts would be appreciated!!

Comment: How many items are we talking? With the database blob field have you just shifted the problem from update a file to update the database every time the list changes? Though with the advantage you can update an individual item rather than the whole list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only deserialize when the application is started.

You need to serialize every time a new item is added (or use the [UnhandledException](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.unhandledexception.aspx) event) if you want to make sure that no items are lost if the application crashes.

If not, I would use a background thread to serialize the list when new items are added and a serialization from the main thread when the application is exited.

> The solution I thought of is to hold a local database with a BLOB column to which the Objects will be serialized to, but I'm not too sure of this approach.

I don't see any benefits of using a database. It will actually be slower than serializing everything to a file.

Comment: not sure about slower, an embedded database that runs in process (such as sqlite) can be pretty fast. If changes are infrequent then it probably won't matter. A user manually clicking a button can normally be considered infrequent. If the changes are frequent (e.g., collecting sensor data) then you would just have a periodic flush rather than save after every change.

Answer (score 0):

I would add simple `ORM` to, let's say Sqlite database and would avoid standart binary serialization. I, personally, don't like it too much as in case of changes applied to the object serialized before (like add/remove properties, change types, function parameters or its sequence) will lead to `deserialization` failure. In other words it's not scallable, **imo**.

Comment: There are several serialization frameworks which has excellent support for versioning.

Comment: @jgaiffin: I'm talking here about *standart* serializatuon, that one which OP uses

Comment: So? I would never switch from `BinaryFormatter` to an ORM/SqlLite. I would switch to a better serialization framework.

Comment: @jgauffin: a matter of architectual choice.

Answer (score 0):

My approach would be binlogging:

- While the application runs, if you delete an object from the list
  just write out a notice of that to a file. If you add an object to
  the list, serialize only this one and write it out again. (All the
  way using filenames such as change-00000000001.del,
  change-00000000002.add etc.)
- When the application shuts down, after final serialization delete all change-* files
- On startup after deserialization (old state), check for change-* files: If they exist, this was a crash and we have to work them up, then do a new serialization and delete changefiles